# Security aspects of an ASP.NET that can be pointed out to the client

Tags: architecture, security, asp.net

I need to write several passages of text in an offer to the client about the security layer in ASP.NET MVC web solution.

I am aware of security that comes along with MVC 3 and an improvements in MVC 4. But all of them are non conceptual, except for `AntiForgeryToken` (AntiXSS) and built-in SQL Injection immunity (with a little of encoding needed by hand).

What would be the main point of ASP.NET security I can "show off" in an offer to the client?

Comment: depends on your client - are they interested in technical information or not?

Comment: Well, anything true and therefore convincing will do.

Comment: A built-in secure Membership Role Provider would be a major feature i would offer.  What else can you think of exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you want to impress, start with a well-respected security report, for example [WhiteHat Website Security Statistics Report
Winter 2011](https://www.whitehatsec.com/resource/stats.html)

Then go through e.g. the top 10 security vulnerabilities, and describe how the .NET framework deals with these issues. I haven't read the report, but I know that the top 10 include SQL injection and XSite scripting.